# Workflow Permissions Block Getting Message

Tags: workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1

Our users do not have "Workflow Management” rights. We do not want them to be able to cancel or force finish Workflow jobs.

We are facing a problem (exception) when the user opens the jobs and tries to see the message left by the previous user. We get the following exception:

> Unable to retrieve item with id Unable to open requested item You do
>   not have permission to perform this action.

We can see that the error is being thrown when the call is made to load the Workflow Activity and the user does not have permission to open it.

It works fine for the users who have either Admin access or "Workflow Management” rights.

Is there a way to grant read-only permission to Workflow Activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved by Hotfix CME_2013.1.1.88509

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can grant Read access for the required groups to the folder that permissions are inherited from. That seems to do it, as bundle permissions are then inherited down to the workflow bundle.

Comment: My situation is a Component Workflow. I think this fix only applies to Bundle Workflow