# Opening component under workflow displays "Unable to retrieve" error for workflow activity

Tags: cme, web8.5, content-manager, workflow

This appears to be the same issue as [Workflow Permissions Block Getting Message](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15517/workflow-permissions-block-getting-message) - I have a user that can read a bundle and the components within it, but when those components are under workflow (started by someone else) when they open the component there's a error notification:

> Unable to retrieve item with id "tcm:263-374068-131104"
>
> Unable to open requested item
>
> You do not have permission to perform this action.

If I add the *Workflow Management* right to this user's group, the error goes away, but the user now has the Administration tab and access to the Workflow Management area which is undesirable.

The resolution in the other article was hotfix CME_2013.1.1.88509 - is this still an issue in SDL Web 8.5 requiring a hotfix?

**UPDATE**

The error also goes away once the workflow activity is *assigned* to my users group. Previously the activity was assigned to a different user - so I guess the error makes sense in one way, user A reading a component user B has under workflow - but it seems like a bug as user A has rights to read the component, it should just show as locked out to the other user's workflow, not error?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with you Neil; whilst you usually can't open an `Activity Instance` if it's claimed by another user; you should be able to open the `Component` from there - showing the last full version. I guess, in 8.5, if you've switched on `Workflow as Collaboration` you should be able to open the minor version of the `Component` in the current version last saved irrespective of who has claimed ownership of it.

Comment: As can be seen in the error message, the problem is not in reading  the Component, but in reading the Activity Instance it is involved in. Indeed, CME will show AI details on the Workflow tab, but if this error is preventing you from opening the Component in the CME, I would call that a defect.

Comment: It doesn't prevent opening the Components - they open (read-only), but then the error notification appears. As I say, this feels like a defect - my user has rights to read the component but not to read the AI (apparently) - that should just leave the component read-only and not need the notification.